# glGetUniformLocation fails for 2/4 fields in a struct?

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl

I've got a struct defined in my GLSL like so:

```
struct Rect {
    float x;
    float y;
    float width;
    float height;
};
```

Which I want to use as a uniform:

```
uniform Rect TextureRect;
```

So in my code I create an array of Uniforms:

```
_hudTexUniform = new[]
    {
        new Uniform(_hudShader, "TextureRect.x"),
        new Uniform(_hudShader, "TextureRect.y"),
        new Uniform(_hudShader, "TextureRect.width"),
        new Uniform(_hudShader, "TextureRect.height"),
    };
```

The constructor of which is defined as so:

```
public Uniform(ShaderProgram shaderProgram, string name)
{
    if (shaderProgram == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("shaderProgram");
    if (Regex.IsMatch(name, @"\s")) throw new ArgumentException("Cannot contain white space.", "name");
    if (name.StartsWith("gl_")) throw new ArgumentException("Cannot start with reserved prefix \"gl_\"", "name");
    Location = shaderProgram.GetUniformLocation(name);
    if (Location < 0) throw new ArgumentException("Name does not correspond to an active uniform variable in program", "name");
}
```

`x` and `y` work perfectly, but when it gets to `width` an exception is thrown ("Name does not correspond..."), i.e., `glGetUniformLocation` is returning -1.

I don't see any typos, and I just checked the GLSL 4.1 spec, and it doesn't look like "width" nor "height" are keywords....so why else would this be failing?

Comment: `width` and `height` are currently being used in your shader? `glGetUniformLocation` is allowed to return -1 if the uniform is not being used, and changing a uniform at that location is defined to do nothing.

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek: Hah. Brilliant. No they're not presently being used... I took them out for a sec while I was working out some other kinks. I'll put them back in and try again...  **Edit:** Yup. That was it. You can make that an answer if you like.

Comment: Done. Glad it was that simple!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`glGetUniformLocation` is allowed, as a convenience to video drivers, to return -1 if the requested uniform isn't actually being used by the shader (dead-stripped, for example). This isn't an error—changes to that uniform via `glUniform*` will be ignored. But that means that you need to treat `-1` as a valid uniform location.

Incidentally, this is probably a good thing for decoupling shaders from your rendering—your code can simply throw all relevant values at the shader and not worry about which ones the shader actually cares about. It also means that you can test to see if a shader actually uses a value and not compute it in the first place if it's not needed.

Comment: Hrm..perhaps I shouldn't be throwing an exception for -1 then :)

Comment: You can throw if you want to be strict about maintaining that the shader and set of uniforms must correspond exactly.  I'm not sure if the driver will optimise any away however.  It might do that.